# How to simplify the nested-loops having index comparison?

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops, simplify

I'm quite a begginer and made a basic nested for loops to modify an existing series(A) of hourly data. The series is made from pandas and having datetime index and value.

My code basically compare the year, month and day index of two serieses(A & B) and if they are same at some rows, change the values of series(A) and make a modified series.

It works for short data but the efficiency is quite poor. 
When I run 10,000 count data, the loop never ends.
Series A is about 10,000 count, Series B is about 1,000 count.

I've already searched similar questions on simplifying nested loops for several days, but I can't handle how to treat the index comparison part, plus I want the object types and index of series A unchanged after the modification. Even a small tip would be very helpful for me.

```
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    for j in range(0,len(B)):
        if A.index.year[i] == B.index.year[j] and A.index.month[i] == B.index.month[j] and A.index.day[i] == B.index.day[j]:
            A.values[i] = B.values[j]
            break
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Would this be what you want to do :

C = A.reindex(B.index).dropna(axis=0);
A.update(B.reindex(C.index))

Note: Update work inplace

Comment: Thank you, Lamine! Can you explain a bit more of your idea?

Comment: the idea is to get the rows of A where their indexes values are also in B then update A with the rows of B that have those values in the index

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might benefit you is [Short Circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Basically, you can make your long conditional statement recognize false results quicker, if your data set is convenient for it. I don't know what the dates you're comparing look like specifically, but consider this example:

Date 1: January 1 2019

Date 2: January 2 2019

Your conditional statement goes through 3 comparisons before ultimately determining that the two dates are not equal.

1. 2019 == 2019
2. January == January
3. 1 != 2

If you were to change your conditional to:

```
A.index.day[i] == B.index.day[j] and A.index.month[i] == B.index.month[j] and A.index.year[i] == B.index.year[j]
```

Your program would first compare the two days, and determine that they are not equal. And because your conditional consists of Boolean AND operations, short circuiting logic concludes that the overall condition must be false.

In this way, only one comparison needs to be done instead of three. However, getting any noticeable improvement from this approach depends on what your dates look like. If your dates are all in the same year, or same couple of years, the approach I mentioned could definitely increase your performance. But if your set contains a wide distribution of months, days, and years, you might not get that noticeable of a change.

Essentially, consider which of your conditions is most likely to return False on an average case. Have that condition evaluated first in your conditional statement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your wise advice! I totally didn't think about the order of the conditions. My data include 2-3 years of period, your advice helps! I did some tests with your idea, it improves 50% in time for 1,000 length data! But as you said, the effect gets smaller around to 30% when the data length increases.. I expect there would be more ways to do the job. Thank you again!